# Use the image inside the database text

Tags: database, image, text

Honorable friends, how do I put text into the image I receive from the database?
Of course, the photo is also responsive, which is great.
Thank you very much

I used Spanable code
The image is taken but the image is not responsive and has a limited image size.

Comment: Where do you try put text? Which language or platform? Html or simple gui?

Comment: What language are you using? Please tag your question correctly.